# Magento static block is not showing on my layout although I followed the instructions correctly

Tags: magento

I want to add a static block on my layout. Therefore from the backend I add a new static block and gave an identifier for that. Then I put my block code inside the page.xml file. This is my code,

```
 <block type="cms/block" name="templatename" template="page/html/templatename.phtml">
 <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>my_id</block_id></action>
 </block>
```

Then I put the php code inside my phtml (templatename.phtml) file to show the data. This is my code,

```
  <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my_id')->toHtml();?>
```

Finally my phtml template file is loading in my layout.phtml file. This is that code,

```
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('templatename') ?>
```

But my static block isn’t showing. Why is that? My Magento version is 1.8

Answer (score 1):

if you want to call cms static block in your custom phtml file
just use below code to call with unique id define by you in admin cms static block section

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my_id'')->toHtml()?>
```

that will sure display your static block in to you custom phtml files.

or you can use detail link

http://importantmagento.blogspot.in/2012/06/magento-how-to-call-static-block-on.html

*i am not associate with above link for any how. it is just for knowledge purpose.*

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: just check visibility and other setting for your static block may be it could make difference.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone....finally i could solve the issue.Only thing i was done,remove the block declaration from the xml file.I just write the php code on my template.Now it works fine.